# Xamarin WebView download file under authentication in iOS

Tags: xamarin, webview, download, uiwebview, xamarin.ios

I am developing a Xamarin Forms application which is basically a WebView where the user have access to some files which is supposed the user have to be able to download.

To achieve this in Android, I have this CustomRenderer for the WebView in the Android project, basically I get the cookies (files are under authentication) to send them to the DownloadManager:

```
public class CustomWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
{   
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            var customWebView = Element as CustomWebView;
            Control.Settings.AllowContentAccess = true;
            Control.Settings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;
            Control.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
            Control.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            Control.Download += OnWebViewDownload;
        }
    }

    private void OnWebViewDownload(object sender, DownloadEventArgs e)
    {
        var source = AUri.Parse(e.Url);
        var request = new DownloadManager.Request(source);

        request.AllowScanningByMediaScanner();

        var cookieString = CookieManager.Instance.GetCookie(e.Url);

        request.AddRequestHeader("Cookie", cookieString);
        request.AddRequestHeader("User-Agent", e.UserAgent);
        request.SetNotificationVisibility(DownloadVisibility.VisibleNotifyCompleted);
        request.SetDestinationInExternalPublicDir(AEnvironment.DirectoryDownloads, source.LastPathSegment);

        var manager = (DownloadManager)MainActivity.Current.GetSystemService("download");

        manager.Enqueue(request);
    }
}
```

The download starts in the background and everyone is happy.

My problem started when I noticed that this behavior is not available in iOS, since the file is displayed on the webview not giving me any option to download or showing the "Open in..." dialog. In plus, after trying to implement a CustomRenderer for the iOS platform too, I see no handler, property or method in the UIWebView or the WKWebView which allows me to manage the download or share the file in another app.

I need to be able to download the file in iOS, or at least, show the "Open in" bar. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to use "shouldStartLoadWithRequest" to catch request that will load page with your file, and download it using your download manager.

Comment: But the download manager does not exist in iOS platform. How do you manage the "file" inside the request to be shared with the default app for example?

Comment: Exist, but not in such fancy way as in Android. You can use "NSUrlSessionDownloadTask" or plain "NSData.FromUrl". Since you'r using Xamarin, you can use "WebClient" for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks @Taier, but this approach opens two new problems to me, the WebClient must be authenticated, is there any way I can copy the webView Cookies to the WebClient? How do I know that the url I am trying to access it is a a file and not a page?

Comment: I may use a dummy querystring for detecting if it is a url for download I think...

Comment: Since cookies are just plain text, you can copy them to webclient one by one. You can detect file by url scheme, or last path component I suppose :)

Comment: Hello @pauades, did you found a solution ? I wonder if it is possible to use WebView cookies in WebClient.